# Using Akka.net with Asp.net on a Modular Monolith architecture

Tags: asp.net, akka, messaging, akka.net, loose-coupling

Iwould like to implement a rest service using Akka and Asp.net.
Following the example [here](https://getakka.net/articles/deployment/aspnet-core.html)

I create my AkkaService containing the FooActor ref and a controller who transform the http request to a RunProcess message which is sent to the FooActor.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : Controller
{

    private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;
    private readonly IAkkaService Service;

    public RebalancingController(ILogger<MyController> logger, IAkkaService bridge)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        Service = bridge;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ProcessTerminated> Get()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        return await Service.RunProcess(cts.Token);
    }
}

    public class AkkaService : IAkkaService, IHostedService
{

    private ActorSystem ActorSystem { get; set; }
    public IActorRef FooActor { get; private set; }
    private readonly IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;


    public AkkaService(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        ServiceProvider = sp;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var hocon = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(await File.ReadAllTextAsync("app.conf", cancellationToken));
        var bootstrap = BootstrapSetup.Create().WithConfig(hocon);
        var di = DependencyResolverSetup.Create(ServiceProvider);
        var actorSystemSetup = bootstrap.And(di);
        ActorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("AkkaSandbox", actorSystemSetup);
        // </AkkaServiceSetup>
         
        // <ServiceProviderFor>
        // props created via IServiceProvider dependency injection
        var fooProps = DependencyResolver.For(ActorSystem).Props<FooActor>();
        FooActor = ActorSystem.ActorOf(rebalProps.WithRouter(FromConfig.Instance), "foo");
        // </ServiceProviderFor>

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    public async Task<ProcessTerminated> RunProcess(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return await FooActor.Ask<ProcessTerminated>(new RunProcess(), token);
    }


public FooActor(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _scope = sp.CreateScope();


        Receive<RunProcess>(x =>
        {

            var basketActor = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<BarActor>(sp), "BarActor");
            basketActor.Tell(new BarRequest());
            _log.Info($"Sending a request to Bar Actor ");

        });

        Receive<BarResponse>(x =>
        {
           ...... Here I need to send back a ProcessTerminated message to the controller
        });


    }
```

Now, let's imagine the FooActor send a message to the BarActor telling him to perform a given task and wait the BarResponse. How could I send back the ProcessTerminated message to the controller?

Few points to take into considerations:

1. I want to ensure no coupling between BarActor and FooActor.
   By example, I could add the original sender ActorRef  to the BarRequest and
   BarResponse. But the BarActor musn't know about the fooActor and
   MyController. The structure of the messages an how the barActor
   respond should not be dependent of what the FooActor do with the
   BarResponse.
2. In the example I only use BarActor, but we can imagine to have many different actors
   exchanging messages before returning the final result to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitpick: you should use [Akka.Hosting](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Hosting) and avoid creating this mock wrapper service around the `ActorSystem`. That will allow you to pass in the `ActorRegistry` directly into your controller, which you can use to then access `FooActor` without the need for additional boilerplate. See ["Introduction to Akka.Hosting - HOCONless, "Pit of Success" Akka.NET Runtime and Configuration" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mnb9W9ClnB0) for a fuller explanation.

Next: to send the `ProcessTerminated` message back to your controller you need to save the `Sender` (the `IActorRef` that points to the temporary actor created by `Ask<T>`, in this instance) during your `Receive<RunProcess>` and make sure that this value is available inside your `Receive<BarResponse>`.

The simple ways to accomplish that:

1. Store the `Sender` in a field on the `FooActor`, use [behavior-switching](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html#becomeunbecome) while you wait for the `BarActor` to respond, and then revert back to your original behavior.
2. Build a `Dictionary<RunProcess, IActorRef>` (the key should probably actually be some unique ID shared by `RunProcess` and `BarResponse` - a "correlation id") and reply to the corresponding `IActorRef` stored in the dictionary when `BarResponse` is received. Remove the entry after processing.
3. Propagate the `Sender` in the `BarRequest` and `BarResponse` message payloads themselves.

All three of those would work. If I thought there were going to be a large number of `RunProcess` requests running in parallel I'd opt for option 2.

Comment: Hi Nitpick, regarding the option 1. would you mean to keep a global field in the FooActor which I set with the sender when receiving the RunProcess request? If that is the case, is it fine (threadsafe) to modify global fields when receiving messages? Also, in this case, what is the purpose of the behaviour-switching if I can't pass arguments (in this case the original sender) to the new behaviour? (Well I tried, but I was not able to switch behaviour passing the original sender)

Comment: If the field is local to the actor's state, then it's perfectly threadsafe since that state can't be accessed or modified outside of the actor's own message-processing, which is single-threaded.

Comment: > Also, in this case, what is the purpose of the behaviour-switching if I can't pass arguments (in this case the original sender) to the new behaviour? 

You can pass argument to a new behavior using a closure:

````
void MyNewBehavior(IActorRef replyTo){ }
```

```
Context.Become(() => MyNewBehavior(Sender))
```

Comment: Hi Aarontheweb,  thanks to your last comment I resolved my problem. Actually, I tried the solution 1(behavior-switching), but I made a little mistake calling Context.Become(x=> MyNewBehavior(Sender)) instead of Context.Become(() => MyNewBehavior(Sender). This throwed the following "You may only call Receive-methods when constructing the actor and inside Become()." . Devil is in the details.. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by simply forwarding the next message to the next actor. The `Tell` operation have a second parameter that can be used to override the message sender. If you're sure that all path has to respond back to the original `Ask` inside the Http controller, you can do this inside the `FooActor`:

```
Receive<RunProcess>(x =>
        {

            var basketActor = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<BarActor>(sp), "BarActor");
            basketActor.Tell(new BarRequest(), Sender);
            _log.Info($"Sending a request to Bar Actor ");

        });
```

This way, the original `Ask` actor is considered as the sender of the new `BarRequest` message instead of the `FooActor`, and if `BarActor` decide to reply by doing a `Sender.Tell(new ProcessTerminated())`. the `ProcessTerminated` message will be sent to the Http controller.

Comment: Hi Greg, actually the other Bar actors have to answer to the Foo actor and not to the original one. Only Foo actor should answer back to the original sender. Let see the foo actor as a choordinator who also has internal logic based on the response of the Bar actors. So unfortunatelly, this solution don't work in my case.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part of the design requirement. Yes, the only way to do it is by storing a dictionary of senders and unique message id and embedding the message id inside an envelope before sending the message along the actor chain. When we receive a reply back from the chain, we can do a lookup based on the message id to recover the original sender.